# How to detect the newness of messages created with the Message module?

Tags: 7, notifications, message-subscribe

I have created messages to notify users that they have been tagged in a picture or that someone commented after them on a thread; pretty much like facebook-style notifications.

**How could I detect if a [message](http://drupal.org/project/message) targeting a user is new to him?**

I had two ideas:

- compare the timestamp of when the message has been created and the
  session timestamp. The session timestamp is refreshed every time a session requests a new
  page so I don't know if I can catch the previous value of this timestamp?
- catch the same event that triggers `drupal_set_message()`.

Would there be any other method to do that?

A recent post "[This is a New Message/You have 4 New Messages](http://drupal.org/node/1073056)" has been submitted in the issue queue of the [Message](http://drupal.org/project/message) module but apparently, it doesn't contain any built-in function to see if the message is new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a custom module with a table containing two columns: `uid` and `lastaccess` and two simple functions.

```
function notifmger_views_post_render(&$view, &$output, &$cache){
    if ($view->name == "notification" && $view->current_display == "page_1"){
        global $user;
        $check = db_query("SELECT * FROM notifmger WHERE uid = :uid",
            array(':uid' => $user->uid))->fetchCol(1);
        if (!empty($check)){
            $update = db_query("UPDATE notifmger SET lastaccess = :time WHERE uid = :uid", array(":time" => time(), ":uid" => $user->uid));
        }
        else {
            $insert = db_insert('notifmger')
            ->fields(array(
              'uid' => $user->uid,
              'lastaccess' => time()
            ))->execute();
        }
    }
}

function notifmger_counter() {
    global $user;
    $msgs = db_query("SELECT count(*) FROM message LEFT JOIN notifmger ON notifmger.uid = message.uid WHERE message.uid = :uid AND message.timestamp > notifmger.lastaccess AND message.type != :type", array(
        ":uid" => $user->uid,
        ":type" => "user_tagged_self"))->fetchCol();
    if ($msgs[0] != 0){
        return $msgs[0];
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my answer to "[How to allow users to manage their own Message Stack messages?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/82)", which IMO is pretty close to the question here. It can be summarized like so:

1. Create a flag (using the the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module).
2. Create a view 'Messages by user'.
3. Use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to flag/unflag messages.
4. Trigger the Rules Component to mark messages (using the [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module).
5. Create notifications about Unread Messages (using the "[Menu Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_badges)" module).

**Note**: no custom coding involved, only using some of the commonly used contributed modules (and "Menu Badges", a hidden gem ...).